# To find $A$ given that $2I + A +A^2 = B$ where $B$ is given.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to find a matrix $A$ such that the following holds:

$$2I + A +A^2 = B,$$ where the matrix $B$ is given. I tried with char poly of $B$ but not getting any idea.

Note that it is also given that $B$ is invertible.

P.S. $B = \begin{pmatrix}-2&-7&-4\\ \:12&22&12\\ \:-12&-20&-10\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: It is not clear to me what invertibility alone brings to the party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an ad hoc method:

It is straightforward (if tedious) to find null spaces of
$B-2I, B-4I, (B-4I)^2$ and determine the Jordan form.

With $V=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & -1 & 1 \\ -6 & 1 & 0 \\ 6 & -1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ we see that
$V^{-1}BV = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$, and since $2+0+0^2 = 2$ we can look for $A$ of the form
$A=\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & \alpha & 0  \\ 0 & \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Then from $A^2+A+2I=B$ we get $\lambda^2+\lambda +2 = 4$ and so $\lambda \in \{-2,1\}$.

Then we need $2 \alpha \lambda + \alpha = 1$ from which we get
$\alpha = {1 \over 2 \lambda +1}$.

Hence $\lambda =-2, \alpha = -{1 \over 3}$ and $\lambda =1, \alpha = {1 \over 3}$ are two solutions (or rather $V A V^{-1}$).

Comment: Looks great! $a_{33} = -1$ would bring additional solutions. Do you have a clue of the additional question that would be :"find all solutions"? Would all solutions be in the form of the one you mentioned?

Comment: I wondered about that too, but need to think about it.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net You probably noticed that loup blanc's answer addressed this point in a nice way.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 2):

So, how about saying that $$(A+{I\over 2})^2=B-{7I\over 4}$$ and starting by finding the square roots of $B-{7I\over 4}$?

Comment: This works, but computing the square root is nontrivial since $B-7I/4$ is nondiagonalizable. One would have to use a series expansion like here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14106/finding-the-square-root-of-a-non-diagonalizable-positive-matrix

Answer (score 2):

According to the other posts, we may assume that $B=\begin{pmatrix}4&1&0\\0&4&0\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$. Note that $B$ is cyclic and that $AB=BA$; thus $A$ is a polynomial in $B$: $A=aI_3+bB+cB^2$.

Then $A$ is in the form -considered by copper.hat-

$A=\begin{pmatrix}u&p&0\\0&u&0\\0&0&v\end{pmatrix}$, where $2+u+u^2=4,2+v+v^2=2$. The sequel is easy; we obtain $4$ solutions

[image]

EDIT. We can also use the Mostafa's trick.

Since $B-7/4I_3$ is cyclic invertible, it admits $2^k=4$ square roots (where $k$ is the number of its distinct eigenvalues). In the same way as above, $\sqrt{B-7/4I_3}$ is in the form

$C=\begin{pmatrix}u&p&0\\0&u&0\\0&0&v\end{pmatrix}$, where $u^2=4-7/4,v^2=2-7/4$.

Comment: What do you mean by $B$ is cyclic?

Comment: Actually, can you elaborate or give a reference in regards to showing that $B$ can be written as a polynomial in $A$?

Comment: @copper.hat , $B$  is cyclic iff  in its Jordan form, for every eigenvalue, there is only one associated Jordan block iff the polynomials in $B$ are the only matrices that commute with $B$ iff there is a vector $x$ s.t. $x,Bx,\cdots,B^{n-1}x$ is a basis.

Comment: Thanks, the commuting with polynomials in $B$ point is an interesting fact to add to my little collection. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$$A=SJS^{-1},\\ 2I+A+A^2=S(2I+J+J^2)S^{-1}=B\\
2I+J+J^2=S^{-1}BS$$
So incorporating (yeah, stealing) the idea of the [Mostafa Ayaz's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3713565) we get $$\left(J+\frac{1}{2}I\right)^2=S^{-1}BS-\frac{7}{4}I$$
Letting, for a second, that $S$ is the same for $$B=S\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0\\0&4&1\\0&0&4\end{pmatrix}S^{-1}$$
we feed this thing to wolframalpha obtaining 
[$$J+\frac{1}{2}I=\pm_{\small{1}}\begin{pmatrix}\frac12&0&0\\0&\pm_{\small{2}}\frac32&\pm_{\small{2}}\frac13
\\0&0&\pm_{\small{2}}\frac32\end{pmatrix}$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B2%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C4%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C4%7D%7D-%7B%7B7%2F4%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C7%2F4%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C7%2F4%7D%7D%3D%7B%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%7D%2C%7Bd%2Cu%2Cv%7D%2C%7Bx%2Cy%2Cz%7D%7D%5E2) and hence $A$. Can [test here](https://tio.run/##PYy/CgMhDMZ3nyJz61XjQQfFB@jW/bhBilCFu@GULnLPbmMohfz5Jfm@bKG@4xZqeoXei/WtTSiBYkJ1PyU0TWgk6MG0ZjydyDi0qIzUkm4km4lRzcw8scxYn5F@mUtyIrHn78BfJxraYH2BG2RD5bF/4lHiUlYnnkfa6xJoG@DKSc9W1/sX)

Comment: Are you assuming $A$ is diagonalisable, or is there a reason why it must be?

Comment: Hmm isn't any matrix diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$? Anyway, we can work the equalities backwards given $B$ is invertable and therefore has complete basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: [Nope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_matrix).

Comment: To the down-voter, I don't think this warrants down-voting. This is a perfectly valid method to attempt to find a solution $A$. The asker didn't ask for all solutions, and this method almost always works.

Comment: It doesn't work in the case with $B$ given in the OP since that matrix is not diagonalizable

Comment: @whpowell96: Why do you say it is not diagonalisable?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says it has a simple eigenvalue of $\lambda = 2$ and a $2\times 2$ Jordan block with $\lambda = 4$

Comment: @whpowell96: Thanks.

Comment: @whpowell96 This answer was written before $B$ was specified. I maintain that the down-vote was unfair.

Comment: I think that since it doesn't explicitly mention the rather large assumption being made it is a fair downvote

Comment: @whpowell96 It's not a large assumption, it's a small assumption. The defective matrices have $0$ measure in the set of square matrices. Without knowing $B$, you are almost surely going to be able to apply this method (which is absolutely the easiest method when it works). The answerer was blindsided by an unfortunate choice of $B$. I agree that the answerer should have included this assumption in the answer, but again, I don't think it justifies the loss of reputation for this small omission.

Comment: 1. The downvote is rather fair if not knowing $B$, as I was not aware that's not the general case 2. on finding the square root [MO comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14106/finding-the-square-root-of-a-non-diagonalizable-positive-matrix#comment24581_14121) " find a Jordan form first (which the general method involves anyway)" I would say my answer adds something useful 3. I'm re-writing $D$ into $J$ 4. WA found a solution (couple, irrespective to the sign), I'll check them before posting edit. Thanks. PS. 5. The reputation loss is rather small compared to intestment to the solution

Comment: @user797616 Just to clarify my point, although nondiagonalizable matrices do have measure 0 in this space, they are of particular import because they break nearly every quantitative result involving eigenvalues and hence result in highly ill-posed problems in computation and unique degeneracies in theoretical work. They are of course "rare" in some sense but they also break nearly every tool we have to analyze matrices in terms of their eigenvalues, including charactierizing polynomials of matrices purely in terms of their eigenvalues, as was done here.